# Web API2 HttpPost denied

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following Web API 2 issue.

The error message is:
The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.

This is the controller.

```
<RoutePrefix("api/Vergoeding")>
Public Class VergoedingController
    Inherits ApiController

<HttpPost, Route("opmerking/{vergoedingid:int}/{remark}")>
  Public Function PostOpmerking(vergoedingid As Integer, remark As String) As IHttpActionResult
  End Function

//JQuery
var opm = $('textarea[id$=Opmerkingen]');
opm.change(function () {
    var a = $(this);
    $.postJSON('/api/Vergoeding/opmerking/'+ vergoedingid, {"remark":opm.val()},
        function () { });
});
```

Whatever I try, even fiddling with web.Config does not make any difference (AcceptVerbs as attribute as well)

The only accepted verb is GET. no matter what, Put or Post, it is not accepted
I also have a correctly implemented config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes.

What do I overlook?
Thanks for any good tips!

Answer (score 0):

Two parameters? Create class with this parameters and create Post method which receives istance of that entity and decorate it with [FromBody]